# Change RDP Port of Windows 2012 R2 server running in amazon AWS

Tags: remote-desktop, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

How do I change the RDP port number of Windows 2012 R2 server running in Amazon AWS?
I could change the port number by going here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
```

but then could not RDP into server even after changing the inbound rules of security group.

Comment: This is resolved. I had to change the firewall settings to allow inbound connection on new port.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. I had to change the firewall settings to allow inbound connection on new port.

Comment: update your question. Do not ask a new question in your answer